# ¿Cómo es posible que si le paso una query con un atributo false me devuelva un resultado con true?

Tags: java, atributos, db4o

Estoy haciendo una query en db4o tengo que buscar viviendas entre 2 precio se me ha ocurrido un bucle pero me doy cuenta de que los resultado son dobles porque si le paso un objeto con atributo false me encuentra tanto el false como el true.

```
public static List ViviendasEntre2Precio(ObjectContainer db, int precio1, int precio2) {
    List<Vivienda> v = new ArrayList<>();
    int mayor, menor;
    if (precio1 > precio2) {
        mayor = precio1;
        menor = precio2;
    } else {
        mayor = precio2;
        menor = precio1;
    }
    for (int i = menor; i < mayor; i++) {
        Vivienda vivienda = new Vivienda(null, i, 0, null, false, null);
        ObjectSet res1 = db.queryByExample(vivienda);
        Vivienda vivienda2 = new Vivienda(null, i, 0, null, true, null);
        ObjectSet res2 = db.queryByExample(vivienda2);
        if (!res1.isEmpty() && res2.isEmpty()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < res1.size(); x++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res1.get(x);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
        }
        if (!res2.isEmpty() && res1.isEmpty()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < res2.size(); x++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res2.get(x);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int z = 0; z < res1.size(); z++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res1.get(z);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < res2.size(); y++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res2.get(y);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
        }
    }
    return v;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la foto el objeto trae el atributo flase y al query da un objeto con true

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Dónde está el problema exactamente (dinos en qué linea ocurre lo que dices)? De lo contrario habría que tratar de adivinarlo.

Comment: Lo pone en la pregunta. Le paso a la query un objeto con un atributo booleano a falso y la query me devuelve un objeto con el booleano a true entonces tengo los resultado duplicados,